# How to check php variables

Tags: php

I have to check if the PHP-Variables are empty or not, I have some code, but I'm wondering if it can more faster.

Daniël

```
if ($beer1 == "" || $beer2 == "" || $beer3 == "" || $beernumber1 == "" || $beernumber2 == "" || $beernumber3 == "" || $wine1 == "" || $wine2 == "" || $wine3 == "" || $winenumber1 == "" || $winenumber2 == "" || $winenumber3 == "" || $name == "" || $adress == "" || $zipcode == "" || $city == "" || $email == "" || $nieuwsbriefjaofnee == "" || ) {
    # code...
} else {
    # code...
}
```

Comment: use an array and loop over empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the *empty* function that php provides for you. See [the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

You also don't want to have that many conditions in the if condition. You could create an array with the values and then loop through it. For example:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (empty($item)) {
        do_sth();
    }
}
```

Just expand it then for you case...

Comment: `$hasEmptyItem=false;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (empty($item)) {
        $hasEmptyItem=true;
        break; /*stop searching further, at least one missing was found*/
    }
}
if($hasEmptyItem){
    /*code...*/
}else{
    /*code...*/
}` - specific code